Using Selenium, that can use browser cookies to stay logged in between sessions
I want to buy a product using Selenium, but every time it opens the browser and I register the purchase, I need to log in to the store site again to finalize the purchase. I don't want it to be like that. I want to provide the username and password to the robot only once, so that every time it opens the browser, it will be automatically logged in to the site.
this is a related part of my code:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
def admin():
        url = r"https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-14079846/"
        # Path to your Chrome user data directory
        chrome_profile_path = r'C:\Users\mehrab\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User'

        # Configure Chrome options to use the specified user data directory
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={chrome_profile_path}')

        # Start a new instance of Chrome with the configured options
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(url)

        def select_color():
            
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bg-neutral-000 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer ml-2 px-2 lg:px-0 styles_InfoSectionVariationColor__pX_3M styles_InfoSectionVariationColor__selected__MqDpU']"))).click()
        select_color()

        # Add a wait before clicking the "add-to-cart" button
        add_to_cart_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='add-to-cart']")))
        add_to_cart_button.click()
        time.sleep(10)  # You can replace this with a more appropriate wait if needed
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.relative.inline-flex.pr-2.pl-0.lg\:p-2.bg-neutral-000.rounded.py-2"))).click()
        time.sleep(10)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'تایید و تکمیل سفارش')]"))).click()
admin()
        

In fact, I want to enter my username and password once, so that every time the robot runs, I won't need to log in using site cookies, and the registered products will be added to my account automatically.

How to save and load cookies using Python + Selenium WebDriver. This will save any cookies (I assume that login sessions will work but it will probably work on most websites so once it has logged in once, you will be logged on again.
